# Refresh datagrid bind to table adapter

Tags: c#, gridview, refresh, datarow, tableadapter

After a failed delete in my grid view, I refresh the binding data in the grid view. All the data is there but the grid view hides the last record(in the row for insert).

But if I click on a header for a filter, the last record is not hidden anymore.

EDIT:

this a part of my code :

```
    private void GridSectionControle_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            demandeService_Section_ControleTableAdapter.Update(lOCAL_CJ_TESTDataSet2.DemandeService_Section_Controle);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            demandeService_Section_ControleTableAdapter.FillBy(lOCAL_CJ_TESTDataSet2.DemandeService_Section_Controle, (int)cmbSousTypeDemande.SelectedValue);
        }
        DeletedGroup = false;
    }
```

Comment: Show some minimal code that demonstrates what is wrong. Is this asp.net, winforms or wpf? Can you explain what you would expect to happen?

Comment: thx ! i fix it with a manually refresh with datasource = null and re affect it

Comment: Please don't add c# to the title, that is where tags are for...